# SQL select records with minimum number of related records

Tags: sql, join, count, having-clause

monkey-hangouts relates many monkeys to many trees and vice-versa.  a monkey hangs out in multiple trees.  a tree hosts multiple monkeys.  the relation monkey-hangouts models the many to many monkeys to trees.

a large proportion of monkeys hang out in only one tree.  i'd like a query of monkeys that hang out in multiple trees.  that is, monkeys with more than one related record in monkey-hangouts.  as a bonus, i'd like the query result to be the monkey X tree join of actual hangouts.

here is a query that selects all of the monkeys with their hangouts. limit this to monkeys with more than one hangout.

```
select 
    m.*, t.* 
from 
    monkeys m 
inner join 
    monkey-hangouts h on m.id = h.monkey_id 
inner join 
    trees t on t.id = h.tree_id 
order by 
    m.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query selects all monkeys and their trees that have more than 1 monkey hangout.

```
select m.*, t.* 
from monkeys m 
inner join monkey_hangouts h on m.id = h.monkey_id 
inner join trees t on t.id = h.tree_id
where m.id in (select monkey_id 
    from monkey_hangouts
    group by monkey_id
    having count(*) > 1)
order by m.id
```

Comment: This works, and returns the monkeys X trees monkey hangouts for monkeys that have more than one hangout. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by aggregating on the monkeys and counting the number of trees:

```
select m.*
from monkeys m join
     monkey_hangouts mh
     on m.id = mh.monkey_id
group by m.id
having count(distinct mh.tree_id) > 1;
```

Edit: `distinct mh.tree_id`

Comment: this works, and returns the monkeys.  wish i could check two answers +1. Thank you!